# Traverse on node XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am not very familiar with xslt. I am trying to traverse through a node to print questions and i have the answers in a seperate node. I need to find the anwers after matching with the question id

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<details>
 <detail>
  <answersall>
    <answers>
        <question id="1"/>
        <answer>4</answer>
        <note>test</note>
    </answers>
    <answers>
        <question id="2"/>
        <answer>2</answer>
    </answers>
   </answersall>
  <detail>
  <questions>
   <question id="1" text="Hello how are you" section="a"/>
   <question id="2" text="how was your day" section="a"/>
 <questions>
<details>
```

I am trying to print something like this
`Question                  Answer`
`Hello How are you          4`
`How was you day            2`
i was able to print the questions using XSL for-each, but i am not sure how i can find the answer. 
I must be able to match the question id and then go to the next node and find the answer and print it.

So far this all i have got with xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2><center>Details</center></h2>
         <table>
             <xsl:for-each select="details/questions/question[@section='a']">
                 <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@text"/></td>
                    <td>????</td>
                 </tr>
             </xsl:for-each>
         </table>
      </body>
    </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have edited my question. Hope it makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `id` of the question to find the answer.  That much you probably already know.  Here's how:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2><center>Details</center></h2>
        <table>
          <xsl:for-each select="details/questions/question[@section='a']">
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="@text"/></td>
              <td>
                <xsl:variable name="id" select="@id"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="//answers[question/@id=$id]/answer"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I chose to take the question's `id` and put it in a variable, and use that variable to locate an answer with the same question id: `//answers[question/@id=$id]/answer` searches for all `answers` that match the `[question/@id=$id]` *predicate* (in XPath speak, the predicate states someting about the node, i.e., a *condition* of that node).  Since your ids are unique, we expect to find only one `answers` node.  Once that node is found, it's further traversed with `/answer`.

I'm not proficient in XSL either, so capturing the question's `id` in a variable to be used in the next line may not be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `<xsl:key>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:key name="answers" match="question" use="@id"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2><center>Details</center></h2>
        <table>
          <xsl:for-each select="details/questions/question[@section='a']">
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="@text"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="key('answers',@id)/following-sibling::answer/text()"/></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think your XML is making the task harder than it needs to be, because you have essentially an ID on an element that neighbors the element it should be on. I think it's simpler with this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<details>
  <answersall>
    <answers>
      <answer for="1">4</answer>
      <answer for="2">2</answer>
    </answers>
  </answersall>
  <questions>
   <question id="1" text="Hello how are you" section="a"/>
   <question id="2" text="how was your day" section="a"/>
  </questions>
</details>
```

Then we can replace the complex XPath statement for the answer with this one:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('answers',@id)/text()"/>
```

The trick here is using `xsl:key` to produce a kind of index to the elements you want to look up. This has positive performance ramifications compared to a global search (as @Zachary Young's answer uses), though I doubt the benefit is significant for small documents.

Comment: Yes i know. This is making it even more difficult. Unfortunately i cannot modify the xml. Anyways thanks for trying. And i can make a note of xsl key.

Comment: I edited it and my solution does work now, and will perform better than the other, even without modifying your XML.